# I can't connect my database.Add-Migration is not working .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bek6t.png)
what should i do? Can u Help

I checked my nuget files and all packeges is downloaded

Comment: when sharing code, please share it as text. From the image, it is not enough info to answer your question.

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup). Having said that, I'm not sure I understand your need, can you (in your post) explain what data you have, and what you want your code to do, in order to get the data you need (where you show examples of both the data you have, and the data you need that to become).

Answer (score 1):

EF needs the class that inherits `DbContext`. As you picked `Transport.Api` in the "Проект по умолчанию" dropdown, EF tries to find it in that project. Specify the right project in the dropdown, or specify the project in the command like this: `Add-Migration MigrationName -Project YourProjectName`